# JSX: Emmet auto-completion for elements that contain dots (E.g. Grid.Column)?

Tags: reactjs, webstorm, jsx, emmet

Is it possible to autocomplete elements that contain dots in their name?
 E.g., in WebStorm, if I type `Grid` [tab] I get `<Grid></Grid>`, as expected. However, if I type `Grid.Column` [tab], I get `<Grid className="Column"></Grid>`.

Is it possible to escape the `.`, or, by any other means get Emmet to recognize it as part of the element name instead of a className property?

Comment: I doubt about it (that you can "escape" the dot symbol here; especially in such straight forward way). But you may create custom [Live Template](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Live+Templates+%28Snippets%29+in+PhpStorm) that will be expended into custom code -- that *may* do (not 100% sure, but good chance). P.S. All standard Emmet abbreviations are implemented using Live Templates .. so Live Template should have priority over dynamic Emmet expression.

Comment: Thanks for replying. OK. It's a shame though, I'm so used to working with Emmet that it's hard to accept that it might not be possible.

Comment: But that's how Emmet works -- it uses `.` to denote the class. I personally do not know the syntax that would allow treating it there as part of the element itself (even in original Emmet). Have a look yourself -- maybe you will find it: https://docs.emmet.io/abbreviations/syntax/

Comment: @LazyOne I did read through, was hoping there'd be some undocumented black magic I could make sure of. I just sent an email to info@emmet, let's see what they get back with. Will reply here once they do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

**From Sergey at Emmet** (after emailing info@emmet.io):

> Hi, currently, there’s no special syntax that allows dots in tag name.
>   Although it’s possible to implement some sort of escaping, generally
>   it’s not a good idea since it may break abbreviation extractions from
>   text content in some cases.